# "Unexpected end of JSON" input when converting a "attrs.$observe" returned value from JSON

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am setting up a directive that acts as a `<select></select>` element but has a little bit of tweaks in it where multiple `<li></li>` elements are being appended.

In my **DIRECTIVE**, I have this...

### baseTemplate.js

```
scope: {
     options: '@',
},
link: (scope, element, attrs) => {    
    // options = ['a', 'b', 'c'];    
    attrs.$observe('options', value => {
         value = angular.fromJson(value);
         scope.stored_options = value;
    })
}
```

the `value` that was returned by `attrs.$observe` was `json`. `value = '["a", "b", "c"]';` as of now, no error occured.

But, As I converted it into an `object` by using `angular.fromJson()` method. An error occured saying, `"Unexpected end of JSON"`

Although the value was converted into an OBJECT, I am still able to use it.

I just hate it when an error occurs inside my console when, technically, there's no error.

Comment: With JSON, strings are use quotation marks. Single quotes are not valid delimiters for strings. Don't confuse JSON with JavaScript. See [JSON.ORG](http://json.org/).

Comment: Yeah, I guess I was just confused. Already edited it. Thank you for that information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of evaluating the attribute as JSON, consider:

```
scope: {
     options: '@',
},
link: (scope, element, attrs) => {    
    // options = ['a', 'b', 'c'];    
    scope.stored_options = scope.$eval(attrs.options);
}
```

The JavaScript-like parser of `$eval` is more versatile than the JSON parser.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS scope/rootScope Type API Reference - $eval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval)